# Vue Javascript Transition not working when calling done()

Tags: vue.js, transition

I am trying to create a transition that scatters vue span elements, and have tried to follow Vue Documentation by calling the done() function at the end of the -after transition hook code. Wondering how to use done() properly?

```
leave: function(el, done) {
      el.style.transition = "all 2s ease-out";
      el.style.top = Math.random() * 15 * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) + "em";
      el.style.left =
        Math.random() * 15 * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) + "em";
      el.style.opacity = 0;
      done()
}
```

When using the done() function no transition occurs. But without the done() function the transition works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from the fact that you are trying to use one type of transition while trying to use the tools for another.

Vue has multiple transition types; the one you're trying to use is programmatic - binding an `enter` or `leave` (or both) methods allow you to programmatically change aspects of an element without being limited by CSS. This, however, requires Vue to know when you're done, which is why the `done` callback exists.

If you'd like to see how your example would look with this, this snippet should illustrate it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example-4',
  data: {
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
    beforeEnter: function(el) {
      el.style.opacity = 0
    },
    enter: function(el) {
      el.style.top = 0;
      el.style.left = 0;
      el.style.opacity = 1;
    },
    leave: function(el, done) {
      el.style.transition = "all 2s ease-out";
      el.style.top = Math.random() * 150 * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) + "em";
      el.style.left = Math.random() * 150 * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) + "em";
      el.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        done();
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#example-4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#example-4 p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example-4">
  <button @click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter" v-on:enter="enter" v-on:leave="leave" v-bind:css="false">
    <p v-if="show">
      Demo
    </p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

The moment you call `done`, Vue considers your transition over and transitions. Without calling it at all, Vue infers from the `transition` CSS property on your element that it is a 2s transition. This is why omitting `done` works.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks really helped!

How would I be able to create this transition without the css transition property then for done() to be of actual use? 

Basically to make the function entirely programmatic?

Comment: @hydra1 I would go the other way, to be honest. Your issue with the transition is that the final offsets are random, but... does it really matter? If the element ends up being hidden, you might as well have a determined offset path and take advantage of CSS transitions (they're more performant)